# Create Array out of a plain text variable?

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I am trying to create an array from a plain text variable like so in php:

```
$arraycontent = "'foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world'";
print_r( array($arraycontent) );
```

But it outputs the entire string as [0]

```
Array ( [0] => 'foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world' )
```

I would like 'foo' to be [0]
bar to be [1] and so on. Any pointers? Is this even possible?

Comment: What programming language is it in ?

Comment: You have failed to state what language you are using.

Comment: You should always put the programming language as a tag, so that people who have that language as a favorite see your question. Just a tip, will probably get you more answers!

Comment: What language? (looks like php)
Based on that string, a `explode` and a `for each` with `trim` might do what you want.
Is the string static, or where does it come from, can it be trusted?

Comment: Sorry it is in php, the string will come from the options panel of a custom cms page in a wordpress site. Thanks for the tip @Jiddle! New to the stack

Comment: You should choose the right answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If your string was like this:

```
$arraycontent = "foo, bar, hallo, world"
```

With only the commas separating, then you could use explode, like this:

```
$myArray = explode(", ", $arraycontent);
```

This will create an array of strings based on the separator you define, in this case ", ".

If you want to keep the string as is, you can use this:

```
$myArray = explode("', '", trim($arraycontent, "'"));
```

This will now use "', '" as the separator, and the trim() function removes the ' from the beginning and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

YIKES, why are these all so long?

Here's a one liner:

```
explode("', '", trim($arraycontent, "'"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval('$array = array('.$arraycontent.');');
```

Would be the shortest way.

---

```
$array = explode(',', $arraycontent);
$mytrim = function($string) { return trim($string, " '"); };
$array = array_map($mytrim, $array);
```

A safer and therefore better one.  If you have different whitespace characters you would have to edit the `$mytrim` lambda-function.

Comment: If you know or a safer method, share. `eval` is a final resort.. Even then, your asking for trouble

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have input like this, I suggest trimming it and using preg_split().

```
$arraycontent = "'foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world'";
$trimmed = trim($arraycontent, " \t\n\r\0\x0B'\""); // Trim whitespaces and " and '
$result = preg_split("#['\"]\s*,\s*['\"]#", $trimmed); // Split that string with regex!
print_r($result); // Yeah, baby!
```

EDIT: Also I might add that my solution is significantly faster (and more universal) than the others'.

That universality resides in:

- It can recognize both " and ' as correct quotes and
- It ignores the extra spaces before, in and after quoted text; not inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is PHP you could use:

```
$foo = "'foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world'";
function arrayFromString($string){
  $sA = str_split($string); array_shift($sA); array_pop($sA);
  return explode("', '", implode('', $sA));
}
print_r(arrayFromString($foo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variant that based on the input example would work, but there might be corner cases that is not handled as wanted.

```
$arraycontent = "'foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world'";
$arrayparts = explode(',', $arraycontent); // split to "'foo'", " 'bar'", " 'hallo'", " 'world'"
for each ($arrayparts as $k => $v) $arrayparts[$k] = trim($v, " '"); // remove single qoute and spaces in beggning and end.

print_r( $arrayparts ); // Array ( [0] => 'foo', [1] => 'bar', [2] => 'hallo', [3] => 'world' )
```

This should give what you want, but also note that for example

```
$arraycontent = "  '   foo   '   ,    '   bar  ' ' ' '  ', 'hallo', 'world'";
```

Would give the same output, so the question then becomes how strict are the `$arraycontent`input?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are having problem while creating an array..
try using

```
<?php
$arraycontent = array('foo', 'bar', 'hallo', 'world');
print_r( array($arraycontent) );
?>
```

its output will be:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => foo [1] => bar [2] => hallo [3] => world
>   ) )